# 'Export Dataset Action' with dynamic SQL query

Tags: toad

My goal is create a "Toad-App" with the Automation Designer which takes a parameter as input and creates an excel-file as output.

The difficulty is that I want to use the input-parameter within the SQL-Query of the *Export Dataset* Action.

As far as I know, this query is not allowed to contain variables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in Toad 12.5. In my test I created an app with 3 actions. A Create Variable, a Set Variable, and an Export Dataset action. My Create Variable creates TEST_VAR with a Global scope. My Set Variable sets TEST_VAR with a global scope. My Export Dataset has a substitution variable in the SQL. Click Set Variables within the Export Dataset action and map the substitution variable to the environment variable TEST_VAR. You cannot do this in Toad 12.1 or earlier.

[image: App]

[image: Create Variable]

[image: Set Variable]

[image: Export Dataset]

Comment: thanks for your answer. That's exactly what I tried to do. Sadly, I am still stuck with Toad 11.6. But good to know, that newer Toad versions can do this :-)

Comment: Tell the person with the money that you need to upgrade! :-)